# How to make Apache serve index.php instead of index.html?

Tags: php, apache, include

If I put the following line in a `index.html` file, to make Apache include the `index.php` file:

```
  <?php include("/Live/ls_client/index.php"); ?>
```

visiting the `index.html` page shows me this:

```
<!--?php include("/Live/ls_client/index.php"); ?-->
```

Why is that? Why doesn't it actually include the PHP file?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As others have noted, most likely you don't have `.html` set up to handle php code.

Having said that, if all you're doing is using `index.html` to include `index.php`, your question should probably be 'how do I use `index.php` as index document?

In which case, for Apache (httpd.conf), search for `DirectoryIndex` and replace the line with this (will only work if you have `dir_module` enabled, but that's default on most installs):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If you use other directory indexes, list them in order of preference i.e.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
```

Comment: You could also do `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` - useful if those are mixed on one server.

Comment: I dislike bubbling up such old (and well-answered) questions, but this solution is not working for me. As proven by "grep -ri 'DirectoryIndex' /etc/apache2/*" , my configuration includes only one DirectoryIndex index line. It is not commented, and the value is DirectoryIndex index.php index.html.  And yet even after restart the server still offers the index.html file - I have to type hostname/index.php to get it to use that file.  I will open an new question if necessary.  UBUNTU-20.04 LTS

Comment: I'm having exactly this same issue and couldn't find where teh DirectoryIndex is. Work around i did is rename my index.html file to index.html.org and next thing is my index.php got picked up by browser. i still like to know where is this DirectoryIndex line is. i remember seeing it in 000-default.conf in sites-available in older apache but its not in apache2 on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: lol, i didn't read the entire thread. DirectoryIndex is in dir.conf file in /etc/apache2/mods-available directory on ubuntu20.04

Answer (score 34):

As of today (2015, Aug., 1st), `Apache2` in `Debian Jessie`, you need to edit:

```
root@host:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ vi dir.conf
```

And change the order of that line, bringing index.php to the first position:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
```

Comment: And still going strong in 2018

Comment: Yey, happy 3yo birthday, dear answer (2 days late)!

Answer (score 7):

PHP will work only on the `.php` file extension.

If you are on Apache you can also set, in your `httpd.conf` file, the extensions for PHP. You'll have to find the line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
                                     ^^^^^
```

and add how many extensions, that should be read with the PHP interpreter, as you want.

Comment: Although you *can* add `.html` extension to the php handler in your apache configuration

Comment: also, the server could be configured to accept index.php as welcome page, eliminating the need for the redundant index.html.

Comment: @MarioP - Yeah, that was the first thing I thought of too. :P Sometimes you have to realize why someone is asking a question to understand how to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by two way once you set priority order like (index.php  index.html ...) for set priority in files go to this directory- `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/nano dir.conf`
and change the order as you wish
2-insecond way you can go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/nano abc.com.conf`
and change in Documentroot directory -`/var/www/abc.com/public_html/`(give file which you want like index.html or index.php)