# Why index.html is called instead of index.php from the root directory?

Tags: php

I have two files on my root directory named 'index.html' and 'index.php'. 
when I browse 'localhost/dir_name' it loads 'index.html'. why 'index.php' is not loaded on the browser..??

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192049/how-to-make-apache-serve-index-php-instead-of-index-html

Comment: `index.html` is the default `DirectoryIndex`. Read more [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load index.php you will need .httaccess at root code for that should be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```