# Getting internal error when trying to access website live

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3

Getting following error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@api.example.com.au to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I pushed live codeigniter project, I updated .htaccess , database file, config file.

.htaccess file contains following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

The Codeigniter project is inside `api.websiteName.com` folder and it is not in `public_html`, if i remove the index.php and htccess file and upload "index.html" file for testing purpose , then index.html works fine but when I upload index.php and .htaccess files back , it says Internal server error 500, There are many answers for same question, I followed answers and did update .htaccess file but nothing works. Folder permissions set as  755 but still getting same error. Any help would be much appreciated.

PHP verison is higher than 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `.htaccess` file  in your code.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
      Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv CI_ENV development
</IfModule>
```

I hope it will help you..

Comment: I replaced it with previous code in .htaccess , but still same error ,

Comment: Can you please your error message show in browser ?

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@api.nfal.com.au to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: you can see this here api.nfal.com.au

Comment: You can check your phpinfo inside `mod_rewrite` is enable or not?

Comment: the problems occur when i upload codeigniter project, otherwise if I upload normal index.html file for testing purpose, that works but when I upload codeigniter project i got error 500

Comment: Can you tell me your server is Shared hosting or Dedicated hosting?

Comment: i am using  VPS server

Comment: You can do it as per suggested answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192049/how-to-make-apache-serve-index-php-instead-of-index-html